# Audit Local User Accounts on Remote Servers

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to conduct an audit of local user accounts for all servers in our environment. I'm running into an issue where the output is divided into separate tables for each device, which is not going to work for thousands of devices! It should just be one large table without repeated headers or spaces in between. Once this is run, it will be exported to CSV for further analysis.

Example:

| Computer | Name | Enabled | PasswordChangeableDate | PasswordExpires | UserMayChangePassword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device 1 | Administrator | False | 2/27/2021 5:00:05 AM |  | True |
| Device 1 | DefaultAccount | False |  |  | True |
| Device 1 | Guest | False |  |  | False |
| Device 1 | WDAGUtilityAccount | False | 1/24/2020 7:30:01 PM | 4/22/2020 8:30:01 PM | True |
| Device 1 | WindowsHelp | True | 2/27/2021 5:00:05 AM |  | True |
| Device 1 | WindowsQuery | True | 2/27/2021 5:00:05 AM | 5/27/2021 6:00:05 AM | True |

| Computer | Name | Enabled | PasswordChangeableDate | PasswordExpires | UserMayChangePassword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device 2 | Administrator | False | 2/27/2021 5:00:05 AM |  | True |
| Device 2 | DefaultAccount | False |  |  | True |
| Device 2 | Guest | False |  |  | False |
| Device 2 | WDAGUtilityAccount | False | 1/24/2020 7:30:01 PM | 4/22/2020 8:30:01 PM | True |
| Device 2 | WindowsHelp | True | 2/27/2021 5:00:05 AM |  | True |
| Device 2 | WindowsQuery | True | 2/27/2021 5:00:05 AM | 5/27/2021 6:00:05 AM | True |

**Code Snippit**:

```
foreach ($device in Get-Content "list.txt"){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $device -ScriptBlock{
        get-localuser | select @{N="Computer"; E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon | ft -a
    }  
}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I correct this to combine the output into one table?
2. Is there a better way of doing this? (I'd certainly hope so!)

Comment: If you find yourself working with tables, you should be aware of [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough I think:

```
$Result = 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content "list.txt") -ScriptBlock {
    Get-LocalUser | 
        Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon 
}
$Result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The parameter `-ComputerName` can take an array of computernames. You don't need a loop for that.

You should not use format cmdlets like `Format-Table` inside a loop. Especially when you plan further steps with the collected data. Collect all needed information first - maybe save them in a variable and just when you output them to the console you can use format cmdlets. Now if you want to output the collected data to a CSV file you can do something like this.

```
$Result | Export-Csv -Path LocalUserList.csv -NotypeInformation -Delimiter ','
```